# PHP Firebase retrieve data help please

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase store, contains two data fields

```
-imagineeringuk
-- data
----temperature
----humidity
```

[image]

And I am using the kreait sdk. Nothing wrong with the SDK I might add, just me.

I don't seem to be able to get any data to come back from the realtime db, so I am here asking for help once more.

I have an index.php (redacted to remove all the guff).

```
<?php 
include('dbcon.php');

$ref = "imagineeringuk";
$getdata = $database->getReference($ref)->getValue();
$i = 0;
if($getdata > 0)
{
    foreach($getdata as $key => $row)
    {
        $i++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['temperature']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['humidity']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="edit.php?token=<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="code.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ref_token_delete" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete_data" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td colspan="6">DATA NOT THERE IN DATABASE</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And the dbcon.php file here ...

```
<?php
   require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

   use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
   use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

   // This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
   // as this PHP file.

   $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/imagineXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json');

   $database = $factory->createDatabase();
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea what Im missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be passing the name of your database (`imagineeringuk`) to `getReference()`. Instead you pass the DB name during initialization (`withDatabaseUri` ) and then either pass the path within the database you want to get, or nothing, to `getReference()`.

Comment: thank you Frank! Superstar, that worked perfectly. I must have been staring at that for too long, but you got it straight away. Thankyou again!